How can I check in an extra bag on an Etihad flight operated by American Airlines?
I am flying from Houston to Abu Dhabi in Economy. Flight is sold by Etihad but has an American Airlines leg from Houston to Chicago. Baggage Allowance is just 1 bag. Etihad website has an option to pay for extra baggage but would not let me since the first leg is operated by American Airlines.
I was wondering if I can check-in an extra bag with American Airlines at the airport  after paying the surcharge. I hope I don't get denied checking in the extra bag at the airport.
Does anyone know?

Have you tried managing your booking on the AA website? If it doesn’t work with your PNR, there may be another one to request from Etihad (or if you are lucky it’s shown somewhere in your booking on the Etihzd site or in the confirmation e-mail).

Related facts in this question.

@DavidRecallsMonica Thanks, My question was if AA would let me check-in an extra bag in addition to the free first bag. I know for the flights that have an AA starting leg AA baggage policies apply.

@erase.ego If you know you need to check in an extra bag, you need to start contacting the companies involved and pre-emptively pay for this. This is much cheaper than doing it at the counter and is a reserved spot, guaranteeing you the extra luggage. You can always try it at check-in, but that's risky and much more expensive.

@Nelson For AA, the difference between prepaying and not showing up is just a few bucks. And have you ever had an airline refuse to check a bag because you didn't have a "reserved spot"? I have never had this happen on a full-size passenger airplane.

@Sneftel Of course they'll never refuse it, but reserved spots will have more guarantees than ones you do at the counter. For one, if the weight limit was reached, your on-the-spot checked luggage will be lower priority and they'll send it over on the next flight.

And have you ever had that happen? I sure haven't. (I've had bags end up on different flights, but not because of weight limits.) It's really, really rare for a passenger jet to hit a weight limit like that. That's why all major airlines also provide cargo services: to use up their excess capacity.

For that matter, I cannot see why any airline would bother prioritizing "reserved" luggage like that, given the additional operational complexity it would require. Do you have any examples of airlines saying they'd do that? (It's the sort of thing they would definitely mention since it's to their benefit for customers to pre-pay.)

Yes, you'll be able to check the extra bag.
Ordinarily there should be no fee for this, as long as it's actually a connecting flight (i.e. with only a few hours between one flight landing and the next flight taking off). Under IATA policies, the baggage terms of the "Most Significant Carrier" (in this case Etihad, since they're flying you to a completely different continent) should apply to all segments. However, this is something that airlines sometimes "forget" about, demanding that you pay extra. (In my experience, American Airlines does handle this properly.)
When you check in, just indicate the total number of checked bags at the kiosk. If there is an additional fee, you can pay it on the spot. There's no need to arrange this ahead of time.

Thank you. I checked my email and went through the "fine print" and noticed that they explicitly mention that the first leg is sold and marketed by American Airlines and the remainder by Etihad. What this means is that I might have to pay while checking in at the airport.

That doesn’t impact the rules. If they’re on the same itinerary then Etihad’s policies control.
